# Typescript :: in an object, use key string to compute its value type

Tags: typescript, tsc, fastify, typescript-compiler-api

I have found this fantastic fastify plugin (https://github.com/Coobaha/typed-fastify) that uses the following syntax to infer the correct types passed to the Service, given a schema of type T.

```js
import {Schema, Service} from '@coobaha/typed-fastify';


interface ExampleSchema extends Schema {
  paths: {
    'GET /test/:testId': {
      request: {
        params: {
          testId: {
            type: 'string',
          }
        };
      };
      // other properties, not relevant for question
    };
  };
}

const exampleService: Service<ExampleSchema> = {
  'GET /test/:testId': (req, reply) => {
    const testId = req.params.testId // this passes ✅
    const testName = req.params.testName // this fails  
 
    // rest of handler
  }
};

// example is simplified. Find a full example here: https://github.com/Coobaha/typed-fastify
```

This plugin is already awesome, but I want to take it even further.

Given a `/test/:testId` string, we *already know* which parameters that URL needs. Having to specify it twice (in the URL *and* the `params` object), it seems to me something worth trying to automate in order to guarantee they always stay in sync.

I would love to find a way to automatically add the `params` type, computing it from the key string (the endpoint URL). For example, the key `/test/:testId` should have a `params` of type `{testId: string}`.

Imagine doing:

```js
import {Schema, Service} from '@coobaha/typed-fastify';


interface ExampleSchema extends Schema {
  paths: {
    'GET /test/:testId': {
       // only other properties, no need for explicit params
    };
  };
}

// and still have the same type-checks on the params :
const exampleService: Service<ExampleSchema> = {
  'GET /test/:testId': (req, reply) => {
    const testId = req.params.testId // this passes ✅
    const testName = req.params.testName // this fails  
 
    // rest of handler
  }
};
```

In my understanding, this would be impossible with default typescript features and possibly only with a plugin to use at compile time using ttypescript.

Is there any way I can avoid using alternative compilers and writing my own plugins?

Thanks for any support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) introduced in TypeScript 4.1, though for long paths with many parameters, you'll need TypeScript 4.5 for its detection of tail recursive types: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QMoIBYQC2cyA3gFDLIAOcYeGAXGZVcgNq33MZhSgBzALrMKbNggD2IGMAEBXKHWDSAEtAgB+ZgCNJkgDYQ4IVlQC+rS5fKhIsRCgCiADziFqR3AWLIILyBAAEww0TBx8IhIxGjoGUTNkAHIAcScAFWQAekheLMZcsABJIKTRcwBuKyqbLKzkGChJQmQAdzw6CAA3aDaIHQalQghWySgAa2QAT0l5JKgUeQxBcjrkQjk8MGQQCAgg5DBJZB15YAMD+mBQ1uB6ZBNkO2gsBDAVUzAp6hQAJQgAI4AHnSAAU4EMMAA+ZAAXjIsUhzDBEPcoUsXx+yH+nimcOQ8hA4xAklaICq5ExzgCSje4MhIL8AQgwVCvH4IAEABpkABBBAIfGkcww2GsTL+QIhZAAAwAJKRQDBegB9cyMBVK3qg8xZTUyXq-cwy5CaZCuPiIMD0tFA348-mCgBkCPYKqeIGQoJEyHZgmQIuQjHFTKloXlioNUGQao1keV0Z1JrNjuQLtIHHdoC9Pr9nIDQdYjvIlO+KGw0C6wCQQO8UVDLOl6CwdeIopYVHYAGkPchxhAZjBkK24OwklwGEkhGnfXxBD6ABQLAHMf7Ai2062owgYIFdqFQnkLXGriC4gCUcJhXUkwCCNRLUhAvCZ7k8OEr1YgzArUCrNdcN8vEiNshVYVIMmyQp8kKEoymQJdASPM8DCmS9YRhGIqCfF9YIOeFlwAOloSFCLw7J6iuUJaAwLBQkAUHJEhw7ZCgAOXcFACMBYjtwwMiIF4djhgow48GuBo4HOUJAF4NwAUneQShEjWBYX0kIcOmCIwoCschKhLfxqDGbZhSAA)

```
type ExtractParams<T extends string, Acc = {}> =
  T extends `${infer _}:${infer P}/${infer R}` ? ExtractParams<R, Acc & { [_ in P]: string }> :
  T extends `${infer _}:${infer P}` ? Acc & { [_ in P]: string } :
  Acc

type Service<Schema extends BaseSchema> = {
  [K in keyof Schema['paths'] & string]: (req: Req<ExtractParams<K>>, reply: Reply) => void;
}

const exampleService: Service<ExampleSchema> = {
  'GET /test/:testId': (req, reply) => {
    const testId = req.params.testId // this passes ✅
    const testName = req.params.testName // this fails ✅
  }
};
```

The magic is in the `ExtractParams` type. This works by trying two patterns. First, it checks for `*:(param)/(rest)`. If this matches, it adds the inferred `param` to the accumulator and recurses on `rest`. This catches parameters in the middle of a query (e.g. `GET /test/:HERE/later`). Then, it checks for `*:(param)` to detect parameters at the end (e.g. `GET /test/:testId`). If neither of these match, then processing has finished and it returns the accumulator, with any inferred parameters.

Comment: THIS is exactly what I was looking for. I never imagined I could use `ExtractParams` in this way! Thanks so much.